# Setting up comfy cms fails with multi-tenancy app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apartment-gem, comfortable-mexican-sofa

I've got an app for which I'd like to use the comfy cms. I did the following:

1. added gem "comfortable_mexican_sofa", "~> 2.0.0"
2. bundle install
3. rails g comfy:cms

When I try to migrate I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)
/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.2/gems/comfortable_mexican_sofa-2.0.19/lib/comfortable_mexican_sofa/routes/cms_admin.rb:5:in `comfy_route_cms_admin'
```

Here is my routes.rb

```
class SubdomainConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.subdomain.present? && !Apartment::Elevators::Subdomain.excluded_subdomains.include?(request.subdomain)
  end
end


Rails.application.routes.draw do


  constraints SubdomainConstraint do
    root "static_pages#welcome", as: 'team_root'
    
    resources :groups
    resources :bookings
    resources :time_tables
    resources :access_codes
    resources :business_hours

    devise_for :users, controllers: {invitations: "users/invitations",  registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions', confirmations: 'users/confirmations', omniauth_callbacks: 'users/omniauth_callbacks'}

  end


  ...

  root "static_pages#index"
  comfy_route :cms_admin, path: "/admin"
  
  # Ensure that this route is defined last
  comfy_route :cms, path: "/"
end
```

When I uncomment *comfy_route :cms_admin, path: "/admin"*, I can migrate and start the server. So I think there is something wrong with my routes, but I don't know what. I also use the apartment gem for multi tenancy.

Answer (score 1):

The latest (2.0.19) version of Comfortable Mexican Sofa doesn't work properly with ruby 3, someone has already created a [pull request](https://github.com/comfy/comfortable-mexican-sofa/pull/949) with a bug fix, but it's not merged. The best way out now is to install the gem from the [fork of the author of this pull request](https://github.com/restarone/comfortable-mexican-sofa). In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'comfortable_mexican_sofa', git: 'https://github.com/restarone/comfortable-mexican-sofa'
```

Or you can fork this repo and install the gem from your account if you don't want someone to change the gem code.